# "WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it" exception thrown although I am importing in another node

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am trying to append a node to a body element in a xml file like this:

```
  Document document2 = db.newDocument();
  Node node = document2.importNode(document.getFirstChild(), true);
  envelope.getBody().addBodyElement(QName.valueOf("com:createLicense")).appendChild(node);
```

and I am getting this exception:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(ParentNode.java:355)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(ParentNode.java:286)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:230)
at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.appendChild(ElementImpl.java:234)
at SOAPClientSAAJ.createSoapEnvelope(SOAPClientSAAJ.java:106)
at SOAPClientSAAJ.createSOAPRequest(SOAPClientSAAJ.java:157)
at SOAPClientSAAJ.callSoapWebService(SOAPClientSAAJ.java:139)
at SOAPClientSAAJ.main(SOAPClientSAAJ.java:47)
```

Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Is `document2` the document behind  `envelope.getBody()` or is it another document? You might be working with three documents in your code, not two.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was working with three documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was working with three documents.

The solution was the following:

```
Document document = db.newDocument();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, document);
DocumentFragment docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
docFrag.appendChild(rootElement);
Document ownerDoc = soapBody.getOwnerDocument();
Node replacingNode = ownerDoc.importNode(docFrag, true);

envelope.getBody().addBodyElement(QName.valueOf("com:createLicense")).appendChild(node);
```